# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is forbidden, check mysqli.allow_local_infile

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is forbidden, check mysqli.allow_local_infile

I am facing this issue in live server while uploading a csv. But i have no problem while running this in my local machine.
After searching the issue i found many people suggest to change

> 'mysqli.allow_local_infile = Off'

to **'On' in php.ini** I have changed it but still now unable to get rid off this problem.

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
> '/home3/xxx/public_html/zzz/apps/assets/uploads/excel/contacts.csv'
> INTO TABLE `tbl_users` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED
> BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (fname, lname,
> email)

My live server php version is PHP Version 7.4.20

Comment: Please check the duplicate carefully, it mentions a couple of other points (configuring the database server to accept this to begin with, and also specifying it when making the database connection.)

Comment: `allow_local_infile` must be enabled both on the client side (PHP in your case) and on server side (edit my.ini or daemon command line options).

Comment: @akina, thanks for your comment, i have changed this value in my php.ini file in my server. But still have the problem

Comment: *i have changed this value in my php.ini file in my server.* This is a half of work. Have you checked or reconfigured MySQL server?

Comment: @Akina, no i have not, what should i have to do in MYSQL server? Should i have to restart it?

Comment: *what should i have to do in MYSQL server?* Either edit my.ini and add `local_infile=ON` into [mysql] section or add `--local-infile=ON` option to service command line or execute `SET SESSION local_infile=ON;` within your connection before executing LOAD DATA. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local-security.html

Comment: @Akina, thanks for your instruction.  My Database client version: libmysql - 5.6.43, should i have to reconfigured this? As your mysql version is 8 i think. One more thing how can i get my.ini in my BlueHost server have you any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233894/discussion-between-rup-and-akina).